# Why strrev() in C is not working with char*?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, gcc

Using C programming, with GCC in windows (with CodeBlocks)
Why this code doesn't work (running it gives empty console window)

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char* str = "hello";
  printf("%s", strrev(str));
}
```

but using an array works fine

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

Note that strrev function prototype is:

```
char *strrev(char *str);
```

Comment: Because `char* str = "hello";` is a *string literal* and cannot be modified. Try `char str[] = "hello";`

Comment: @Wassim You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined  behavior.

Comment: To get a modifiable string from a string literal, you could use `strdup`. Note that this allocates memory that might need to be `free`d.

Answer (score 2):

`strrev()` is for in-place reversal of strings.

Since in your code

```
char* str = "hello";
```

`str` points to a string literal, and an attempt to modify a string literal will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). See the [man page](https://manpages.org/strrev/3) for more details.